# Create Recurring Series of Tasks in lightning experience issue

Tags: lightning-experience, account, tasks, activities, task-recurrence

In my Account layout in each Account record I have a related list allowing me to create Task records.

When I switch to Lightning experience and open an Account record and try to create a new task there is no option to `Create Recurring Series of Tasks`
[image]

How to `Create Recurring Series of Tasks` while I'm in my Account record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [Enable Recurring Tasks in Lightning Experience and the Salesforce Mobile App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tasks_enable_recurring_tasks_lex.htm&type=5). Steps are outlined in the link, but in summary, you will need to:

- Enable the setting `Enable Creation of Recurring Tasks` from Setup --> Activities Settings to enable it for LEX and Salesforce Mobile App
- Add the `Create Recurring Series of Tasks` field on Task page layout

Comment: `Enable Creation of Recurring Tasks` that checkbox was already ticked and it was already enabled. `Create Recurring Series of Tasks` field was added already in my Task page layout. Still no option available to create recurring task while I'm in my Account record. Any ideas on how to solve the issue?

Comment: @lemdev I will keep on looking around to see if bringing this field on the screen as in your post is really available or not. I don't know if there's a way to have it on that particular screen or this is only available only when creating a task by clicking say "New Task" button.